# Display Autocomplete list

Tags: java, selenium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can selenium handle autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663034/can-selenium-handle-autocomplete)

How to display `Autocomplete` list while testing a software application by selenium tool using `javacode` in eclipse  ?