# Selenium does not record Ajax Call. Need help on coding in html or selenese

Tags: html, ajax, selenium, selenium-ide

I am recording a .Net application using Selenium IDE. Theres this scenario, that a textbox is presnt. I need to enter a name to search. As soon as i start typing, matching options come in a dropdown below. I have to select one of them, then the application goes to the next page.

The problem is, Selenium doesnt record this selection from the drop down. More over, when the script is typing in the name, the dropdown list is not being visible at all.. i.e. the ajax call is not occuring.

Please help. I need the solution code in Selenese or HTML, since I'm not much of a coder myself, and also, I am simply recording and playback, so I am not using Java or other scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is great,

and so is the answer in this blog: http://blog.buberel.org/2010/07/howto-test-jquery-ajax-autocomplete-menus-with-selenium.html

other option to deal with this problem is to use a different way to insert your text into the text box, as described here: [Can selenium handle autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663034/can-selenium-handle-autocomplete)

Comment: Hi, I found both the links quite informative and simple to understand. Thanks so much for that. But the thing is, two problems: 1. TypeKeys doesnt work for me. the name isn't typed in the box. even after trying focus befor typekeys. 2. Using sendkeys i managed to get it type the name, but then the auto complete list wouldn't come. Any suggestions?