# How to get an autocomplete to work with java webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, autocomplete, webdriver

I have the following selenium automation code that used to work for an autocomplete dropdown:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='s2id_customer-name-search']/a")
private static WebElement customerDrop;

@FindBy(id = "s2id_autogen5_search")
private static WebElement searchField;

public static void searchByCustomer(String customer) {

    customerDrop.click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(searchField()));
    searchField.sendKeys(customer);
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(searchResult()));
    searchResult.click();

}
```

A change was made to the page in order to resolve an issue with clearing the field, and now the automation no longer autocompletes. Manual entry still triggers the autocomplete, but not with my automation code.

Is there another way to do this that will also trigger the autocomplete?

Comment: Perhaps these links help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202061/test-autocomplete-with-selenium-webdriver and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663034/can-selenium-handle-autocomplete

Comment: From the first link: I am using Selenium 2, so I can't use fireEvent. I tried sending Tab after the sndKeys string, but it just closed the field with no text and moved to the next field. From the second link, I would like to try type, or typeKeys instead of sendKeys, but they do not work with a WebElement, and I'm not sure what I would need to do to use them. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: So, the problem I was running into was caused by incorrect CSS being applied to the input field. Correcting the CSS fixed my automation issue. I still find it weird that this only broke the automation, but caused no problem with manual entry.